# How to invoke a visualforce page from a Lightning component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I need to know how to be able to call a visulalforce page from a Lightning component by a click of a button.

Here is my js controller:

```
   gotoURL : function(component, event, helper) {
   var urlVf = new URL("{!URLFOR($Page.someVisualForcePage)}");
   var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
   urlEvent.setParams({
    "url":"urlVf"
   });
   urlEvent.fire(); }
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:-

```
 gotoURL : function(component, event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url":"/apex/vfpagename?parametername="+"parametervalue"
        });
        urlEvent.fire(); }
```

Comment: Instead of using force:navigateToURL, we recommend navigating to web pages using the lightning:navigate component with the standard__webPage page type. For more information, see the Lightning Components Developer Guide. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation